# ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I have this output :

> [Pandas-profiling] ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic'

when trying to import pandas-profiling in this fashion :

```py
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

It seems to import pandas-profiling correctly but struggles when it comes to interfacing with pandas itself. Both libraries are currently up to date through conda. It doesn't seem to match any of the common problems associated with pandas-profiling as per their documentation, and I can't seem to locate a more general solution of importing the name `ABCIndexClass`.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have the error when running ` from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`, please check that all your modules and pandas are really up to date.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks to the @aflyingtoaster's answer, the following workaround has worked fine for me:

1. Edit the file "~/[your_conda_env_path]/lib/site-packages/visions/dtypes/boolean.py"
2. Find the row "from pandas.core.dtypes.generic import ABCIndexClass, ABCSeries" and just replace ABCIndexClass for ABCIndex.
3. Save the boolean.py file and enjoy your report!

Comment: Worked like a charm, better solution imo as it doesn't require you to downgrade your version of pandas.

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm for me. Here is the location of boolean.py file
C:\Users\MyUser\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\visions\dtypes

Comment: Also like this solution more. For me on an Linux-based Azure Compute Instance, the correct path was ``/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/visions/dtypes/boolean.py``.

Answer (score 21):

Pandas v1.3 renamed the `ABCIndexClass` to `ABCIndex`. The `visions` dependency of the `pandas-profiling` package hasn't caught up yet, and so throws an error when it can't find `ABCIndexClass`.  Downgrading pandas to the 1.2.x series will resolve the issue.

Alternatively, you can just wait for the `visions` package to be updated.

Comment: This worked for me.  Just run the pandas installation again specifying v1.2  Hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: Update on it's way: https://github.com/dylan-profiler/visions/pull/192

Comment: @Simon any word?

Comment: I had the same issue. All I had to do was "conda update visions" and it now works

Answer (score 2):

ABCIndexclass to ABCIndex

go to user>annaconda 3>Lib> site package > visions > dtypes > boolean.py

open boolean.py in words

go to line where it says ABCIndexclass and change it to ABCIndex

Comment: interesting workaround and it works. Obviously it is not good in terms of package integrity and compatibility but I like this little tweak as a short cut.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in colab and none of the previous answers covered that environment, so I'd like to share what works for me - `!pip install https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip` which just simply install the latest pandas-profiling instead of the default one or 2.7.1 etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Anaconda** distribution, another solution is to first update

```
conda update --all
```

Then delete every folder related to **pandas_profiling** at `~/[your_conda_env_path]/Lib/site-packages/`.
For example:

- pandas_profiling
- pandas_profiling-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info
- ...

Later, use this CLI to install the package

```
conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling
```

It worked for me while using https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64.exe

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users, this was the path I needed:

```
/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/visions-0.5.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0/site-packages/visions/dtypes/boolean.py
```

Removing 'index' from 'ABCClassIndex' worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `pandas 1.3.x`.

Alternatively downgrade the pandas package to `1.2.x`.

You can do that from `Anaconda Navigator`. Go to `Environments` and downgrade pandas package.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For colab user you can try upgrading to the `3.4.0`

```
pip install pandas-profiling==3.4.0
```

The issue is resolved in this version.

Answer (score -2):

Just installed the "visions" package and it fixed for me.

pip install visions