cannot import name 'astype_nansafe' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.cast'
While importing ProfileReport from ydata_profiling, I got this error "cannot import name 'astype_nansafe' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.cast'"
I couldn't find anything on this error couldn't understand why it won't import can anyone help me?

Similar reports, although not about astype_nansafe specifically, all point to issues in versions of modules using pandas. Please state the versions of modules in your mre. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704002/12846804. Updating your environment may be a solution.

With "mre" I meant this: [mre]

Please check your pandas version in your environment. If you look at the release notes, astype_nansafe() was only added in 1.5.0 version.
Assuming no other dependencies, upgrading to at least 1.5.0 should solve this particular error.
